# Will a sql server product key still work after moving a virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, sql-server, product-key

A virtual machine that we have is going to be moved onto a different box.

The MAC address, hostname and ip address will change, but other than that everything on the OS will be an **exact** copy

Would this invalidate a Sql Server Product Key?

If it does, do I need to get a new key prior to doing this?

Comment: No;  it should be fine;

Comment: Changing the IP address and the host name could have an impact on apps, processes, etc. pointing to it by either of those.... you should also look over the accepted answer here for changing applicable default instance meta data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198491/sql-server-servername-returning-old-machine-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're moving a VM from one host to another, SQL Server won't even know anything is different.

However, changing the **hostname** of a server is a completely different operation, and that **will** have an effect on SQL Server.  In my experience, SQL Server doesn't like having the hostname change.  You can work through it by making configuration changes within SQL Server, but unless you have some good reason to change the hostname, I would avoid doing that.  VM's can move around while retaining their settings.  You should even be able to keep the IP address as long as it's staying on the same subnet.

As far as the license key is concerned, there's really no concern at all.

Comment: The subnet and ip address have to change in my instance. Technically we *could* keep the old hostname, but naming conventions. I'll start looking at the settings of SQL Server and try to find the config settings where it references hostname. I'm hoping SQL Server relies on plain hostname and doesn't care about the actual IP of the box?

Comment: Great link on this => [MSDN Rename a Computer that Hosts a Stand-Alone Instance of SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx)

Comment: That's correct - SQL server doesn't care about the IP address.  Good luck with the hostname change.  Incidentally, I mentioned the license, and it's true that you won't get any errors concerning the key.  However, you may want to check with Microsoft or your vendor to make sure you won't be in violation of any terms.  There are several different licensing structures for SQL server, and they can get pretty confusing.